# Msg 544, Level 16, State 1 error procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

When trying to run an insert statement:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_register]
@code int output,
@name varchar(50),
@description varchar,
@phone int
as
insert into user (code,name,description,phone)
values (@code,@name,@description,@phone)
set @code = @@IDENTITY
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_register, Line 8
>   
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'user' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Also please, please, please don't ever use @@IDENTITY. You should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY() in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert into the `code` column, because it's automatically generated.
Change it to:

```
insert into user (name,description,phone)
values (@name,@description,@phone)
```

Comment: should you come across this again, and you DO actually need to add values into an identity column (usually this is bad practice, but it happens once in a while anyways...) do as follows: SET IDENTITY_INSERT user ON then the rest of your stored procedure then SET IDENTITY_INSERT user OFF